# How to disable console output on Rails 3 development server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, console, mailer

How can I disable the console output on a Rails 3 application?
More specifically, I want to disable at least the Mailer output, that outputs the entire email content, including the pictures, making the action processing much slower (it takes almost 10sec to send an email).

ps: I think the slowdown is because of the output, if it can be from another source, such as slow smtp server (it's gmail atm, so no.) or something else like that please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By this you mean you want to hide the output shown in the console run you run `rails s` (or `script/server` in rails 2)?

Are you on Linux or OSX?

If so, then just do the following

```
$ rails server 1> /dev/null
```

this sends all output from stdout into a blackhole.

So right now you are trying to send emails from your dev machine?
I try to avoid this,
as accidents are going to happen
and you'll send clients test data.

Try Mailcatcher
http://mailcatcher.me/

It lets you catch all the emails your app would be sending
shows them off in a nice web interface
and importantly avoids the risk of accidentally sending real emails to customers with random test data.

Comment: Thanks, doing so did improve processing time from 6~7s to 4~5s. Not much, but it helps. Also, we're already using MailInterceptor to make sure no client receive any emails.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP server's (even Gmail) response can really take some time. You'd rather use a mail queue that stores all emails in a database and then they are sent by an independent process.

E.g. https://github.com/beam/action-mailer-queue

Concerning logger - make sure that your logging level is :error or :fatal. If not, run:

`config.log_level = :error`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea for me, I may use something like background processing, but not queues. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/development.log')
```