# How to suppress request logging to STDOUT in rails development server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

More precisely, I want all `logger.info/debug/etc` messages to be shown only in *.log file, but not in console window. Thanks.

UPD:
I dont want suppress all of console output, E.g. I want use `letters` gem to put my own output to console, also I want to use `debugger` which wont work with `stdout` redirected to `/dev/null`. I just want rails do not output `Rails.logger` messages to `stdout` (requests, `ActiveRecord` SQL queries, etc), Actually I can see such messages in log-file if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable console output on Rails 3 development server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363982/how-to-disable-console-output-on-rails-3-development-server)

Comment: No, its not. I dont want suppress all of console output, E.g. I want use letters gem to put my own output to console, also I want to use debugger which wont work with stdout redirected to /dev/null. I just want rails do not output Rails.logger messages to stdout (requests, ActiveRecord SQL queries, etc), Actually I can see such messages in log-file if needed.

Comment: Yes, I do that. It's exactly why I dont want to see the same output twice.

Comment: This is surprisingly hard to do.  Looking into it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the following line into your `<environment>.rb` under `config/environments`. E.g. for development, the following goes into `development.rb`

```
config.logger = Logger.new('/path/to/log/development-nostdout.log')
```

This overrides the default logger.

Comment: Yeah! Its cool & painless solution! Thank you very much! PS: It don't work in case when the logger redirected to log/development.log, it needs another log-file.

Comment: This was surprisingly hard to find.